# Hamcrest hasItem and Mockito verify inconsistency

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I've ran into an issue with hamcrest and mockito. 
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class A{
     public void foo(List<B> arg){
          return;
     }
}

public BMatcher extends BaseMatcher<B>{
 //Some impl...
}
```

In my test I want to do something like

```
A a = mock(A.class);
B expected = new B();
Mockito.verify(a).foo(argThat(JUnitMatchers.hasItem(new BMatcher(expected)));
```

However, the `hasItem` matcher returns an `Iterable<B>` while the foo method expects a `List<B>`.
Is there any good way of verifying the method is called properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ArgumentCaptor`.

```
 @Captor
 ArgumentCaptor<List<B>> captor;

 // then in test
 ...
 verify(a).foo(captor.capture());
 List<B> values = captor.getValue();
 assertThat(values, IsIterableContainingInOrder.containingInOrder(new BMatcher(expected));
 ...
```

I used the `@Captor` as a shortcut and also to that it could be a `List<B>` instead of just `List`. This requires the use of `MockitoAnnotations.init(this)` in an `@Before` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'argThat' method in the Mockito Matchers class to convert from a hamcrest Matcher to a mockito argument matcher:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
//....
public static <T> List<T> listWithItem(Matcher<T> m)
{
    return (List<T>)argThat(Matchers.hasItem(m));
}
```