# Mockito and Hamcrest: how to verify invocation of Collection argument?

Tags: java, generics, mockito, hamcrest

I'm running into a generics problem with Mockito and Hamcrest.

Please assume the following interface:

```
public interface Service {
    void perform(Collection<String> elements);
}
```

And the following test snippet:

```
Service service = mock(Service.class);

// ... perform business logic

verify(service).perform(Matchers.argThat(contains("a", "b")));
```

So I want to verify that my business logic actually called the service with a collection that contains "a" and "b" in that order.

However, the return type of `contains(...)` is `Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>>`, so `Matchers.argThat(...)` returns `Iterable<String>` in my case, which naturally does not apply to the required `Collection<String>`.

I know that I could use an argument captor as proposed in [Hamcrest hasItem and Mockito verify inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174192/hamcrest-hasitem-and-mockito-verify-inconsistency), but I would very much like not to.

Any suggestions!
Thanks!

Comment: Casting a `Matcher<Iterable<String>>` to `Matcher<Collection<String>>`? That surely won't compile...

Comment: If you know collection type and collection has **correct** `equals` implementation then you can call `verify` with collection instance that contains 'a' and 'b'. But this would be bad test - first you will  explode implementation details as well you have to relay on correct equals method. So I would use argument captor without doubts

Comment: I don't know how far you would go to avoid argument captors, but maybe you could implement a custom matcher like `IsListOfTwoElements` here: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unsurprisingly, I don't like either of them. Guess I'll have to use those argument captors after all. :-(

Comment: Can't you just write `verify(service).perform((Collection<String>) Matchers.argThat(contains("a", "b")));` ?

Comment: You cannot verify "in order" on `Collection` since `Collection` is not guaranteed to be an ordered collection.  Are you sure you meant Collection and not `List`?

Comment: @KevinWelker, assume `containsInAnyOrder` then, which has the same signature.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can just write

```
verify(service).perform((Collection<String>) Matchers.argThat(contains("a", "b")));
```

From the compiler's point of view, this is casting an `Iterable<String>` to a `Collection<String>` which is fine, because the latter is a subtype of the former.  At run time, `argThat` will return `null`, so that can be passed to `perform` without a `ClassCastException`.  The important point about it is that the matcher gets onto Mockito's internal structure of arguments for verification, which is what `argThat` does.

Comment: `contains` returns a `Matcher<Iterable<? extends String>>`, not a `Matcher<Iterable<String>>`, so without `@SuppressWarnings` you're going to get an unsafe cast warning in there somewhere. Same goes for `containsInAnyOrder`, which would also work.

Comment: which contains do you use? i only finde contains(String substring)

Comment: Just so as to keep this up to date; an easy way to do this with Kotlin is: `verify(service).perform(argThat { "b" == this["a"] })`

Comment: @barracuda317 they are using org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains().  I managed to solve this using org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.hasItems() instead.

Comment: Since mockito 2.1.0 you need to use MockitoHamcrest.argThat. https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative one could change the approach to `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // needed because of `List<String>.class` is not a thing
// suppression can be worked around by using @Captor on a field
ArgumentCaptor<List<String>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

verify(service).perform(captor.capture());
assertThat(captor.getValue(), contains("a", "b"));
```

Notice, that as a side effect this decouples the verification from the Hamcrest library, and allows you to use any other library (e.g. Truth):

```
assertThat(captor.getValue()).containsExactly("a", "b");
```

Answer (score 12):

If you get stuck in situations like these, remember that you can write a very small reusable adapter.

```
verify(service).perform(argThat(isACollectionThat(contains("foo", "bar"))));

private static <T> Matcher<Collection<T>> isACollectionThat(
    final Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> matcher) {
  return new BaseMatcher<Collection<T>>() {
    @Override public boolean matches(Object item) {
      return matcher.matches(item);
    }

    @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
      matcher.describeTo(description);
    }
  };
}
```

Note that David's solution above, with casting, is the shortest right answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the hint that Mockito matchers return `null`. If @DavidWallace does add his comment as a reply, I will accept his answer though. Hope you won't mind. :-)

Comment: @Philupp It's only fair! He just did answer, FWIW, so I'm editing down mine to avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 12):

You can put your own lambda as an `ArgumentMatcher`

```
when(myClass.myMethod(argThat(arg -> arg.containsAll(asList(1,2))))
    .thenReturn(...);
```

Comment: Awesome! And if you want to check for an empty collection you could just use `argThat(Collection::isEmpty)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just verify with the expected arguments, assuming the list only contains the two items, e.g.:

```
final List<String> expected = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b");
verify(service).perform(expected);
```

Whilst I agree with Eugen in principle, I think that relying on equals for String comparison is acceptable... besides, the `contains` matcher uses equals for comparison anyway.

Comment: This example depends on the order of elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer here you can do the following:

```
verify(yourmock, times(1)).yourmethod(argThat(arg -> arg.containsAll(asList("a", "b"))));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have your own java.util.Collection implementation and override the equals method like below.

```
public interface Service {
    void perform(Collection<String> elements);
}

@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    Service service = mock(Service.class);
    service.perform(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b")));
    Mockito.verify(service).perform(Matchers.eq(new CollectionVerifier<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b"))));
}

public class CollectionVerifier<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public CollectionVerifier() {

    }

    public CollectionVerifier(final Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Collection<?>) {
            Collection<?> other = (Collection<?>) o;
                return this.size() == other.size() && this.containsAll(other);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```