# Mockito/JMockit & Hamcrest matchers : How to verify Lists/Collections?

Tags: java, generics, mockito, jmockit, hamcrest

This [2013 post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20441594/827480) asked how to use Hamcrest matchers to verify lists/collections invocations in Mockito.  The accepted solution was to cast the Matcher to a (Collection).

I'm trying to do something similar, but running into a class cast error.  I am not sure if I am misusing Hamcrest matchers, or if this usage simply isn't supported by Mockito.  In my case, I'm trying to use a list of Matchers as my argument:

```
static class Collaborator
{
   void doSomething(Iterable<String> values) {}
}

@Test
public void usingMockito()
{
   Collaborator mock = Mockito.mock(Collaborator.class);
   mock.doSomething(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));

   // legal cast
   Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething((Collection<String>)argThat(Matchers.contains("a", "b")));
   // legal cast
   Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething((Collection<String>)argThat(Matchers.contains(Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b"))));

   // illegal cast!!! Cannot cast from Iterable<capture#3-of ? extends List<Matcher<String>>> to Collection<String>
   Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething((Collection<String>)argThat(Matchers.contains(Arrays.asList(Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b")))));
}
```

But I get the cast error:

```
Cannot cast from Iterable<capture#3-of ? extends List<Matcher<String>>> to Collection<String>
```

Am I doing something unsupported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeff Bowman has already pointed out, the problem is that the compiler doesn't know which of the 4 `contains` methods you are trying to call.

The list you are constructing

```
Arrays.asList(Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b"))
```

is of type

```
List<Matcher<String>>
```

but the `contains` method you want to call (`<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(List<Matcher<? super E>> itemMatchers)`) expects a type

```
List<Matcher<? super String>>
```

as parameter. As your list type doesn't match the expected one, the compiler actually thinks that you are trying to call

```
<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items)
```

The solution: give the compiler what it wants. Create a `List<Matcher<? super String>>` instead of a `List<Matcher<String>>`:

```
        List<Matcher<? super String>> matchersList = new ArrayList<>();
        matchersList.add(Matchers.equalTo("a"));
        matchersList.add(Matchers.equalTo("b"));

        // no illegal cast anymore
        Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething(
            (Collection<String>) argThat(Matchers.contains(matchersList)));
```

EDIT:

Adding Jeff Bowman's inline solution from his comment, that enables the use of `Arrays.asList` as stated in the question:

```
Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething(
   (Collection<String>) argThat(
        Matchers.contains(
            Arrays.<Matcher<? super String>> asList(
                Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b")
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the callout! +1, and you might also be able to do this inline by parameterizing `asList` (i.e. `Arrays.<? super String>>asList(...)`).

Comment: @JeffBowman great. I will add it to the answer, hope you don't mind

Comment: Please do! I didn't get a chance to test it, but you articulated a very good answer with a very specific explanation, and should definitely get due credit for that.

Comment: Overloading is not the cause; see my comment to Jeff's answer.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of `Mockito MockitHamcrest#argThat` rather than `Mockito#argThat` should be used.

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer use `allOf`

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;

...

    Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething(
        argThat(
            allOf(
                hasItems(equalTo("a")),
                hasItems(equalTo("b"))
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to an annoying ambiguity in Hamcrest, which has on its [Matchers class](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html):

1. `<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items)`
2. `<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(Matcher<? super E> itemMatcher)`
3. `<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(Matcher<? super E>... itemMatchers)`
4. `<E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(List<Matcher<? super E>> itemMatchers)`

That's right, depending on whether you pass Hamcrest an item, a matcher, a varargs array of matchers, or a list of matchers, you'll get different behavior. Because Java has no aversion to matching lists of Hamcrest matchers, there is plenty of opportunity for one statement to match more than one of those overloads, and the choice between them is the most specific overload as determined by dizzying type algebra in [JLS 18.5.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.4).

I think you're intending item #4 above—pass `contains` a List of `Matcher<E>` (`Matcher<String>`) and get back a `Matcher<Iterable<? extends String>>`—but the compiler sees it as #1—pass `contains` a *value* of type `E` (`List<Matcher<String>>`) and get back a `Matcher<Iterable<? extends List<Matcher<String>>>>`.

There are a couple workarounds, which I *haven't tested yet*:

- Extract the `Matcher` to a variable, which you can do with Hamcrest matchers like `contains` but not Mockito matchers like `argThat`:

  ```
  Matcher<Iterable<String>> matchesAAndB = Matchers.contains(
      Arrays.asList(Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b")));
  Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething((Collection<String>)argThat(matchesAAndB));
  ```
- Choose E explicitly:

  ```
  Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething((Collection<String>)argThat(
      Matchers.<String>contains(Arrays.asList(
          Matchers.equalTo("a"), Matchers.equalTo("b")))));
  ```

Comment: Wow... I wouldn't have thought of that.  I didn't realize that the compiler would be missing this due to the overloading issue.  I'll run some quick tests and figure out which is the correct statement.  Thx.

Comment: It turns out that overloading is not the cause of the issue. We can see that by adding two dummy methods to the test class, and using them instead of the Hamcrest matchers: `static <T> Matcher<Iterable<T>>           hasItems(T... items) { return null; }` and `static <T> Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> contains(T... items) { return null; }`, where using the first with `argThat` compiles fine, the second does not. The real cause is the use of `? extends T` in the second matcher.

Comment: Yes, that's a good summary: Incompatible bounded generics are the root cause. Please read the OP's error message and you'll see why overloads are a confusing part of the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the standard `assertThat` method (from Hamcrest or JUnit), which will work best with any Hamcrest matcher. With JMockit you could then do:

```
@Test
public void usingJMockit(@Mocked final Collaborator mock) {
    mock.doSomething(asList("a", "b"));

    new Verifications() {{
        List<String> values;
        mock.doSomething(values = withCapture());

        // Now check the list of captured values using JUnit/Hamcrest:
        assertThat(values, contains("a", "b"));

        // Alternatively, could have used Asser4J, FEST Assert, etc.
    }};
}
```

Comment: The Mockito analogue is [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html), for which generic captures may be more-easily-expressed with [`@Captor`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Captor.html). Beware that you may have to work harder to ignore non-matching method calls the way `verify` does automatically.

Comment: @JeffBowman JMockit's `withCapture()` is equivalent to Mockito's `ArgumentCaptor`, I believe; they both support generic types. I am not sure what you meant by "work harder to ignore non-matching method calls", though; isn't that the same with both APIs, as well?

Comment: The question has a Mockito tag, not JMockit, so I was offering the equivalent for the asker's sake. I imagine both capturing solutions are the same, but _compared to a solution where you pass a Matcher into Mockito_, any capturing solution gets complicated _when there are multiple calls to the same method_. Then your captor will have multiple values to check, not just one, and you'll need to assert that _any_ of them match.

Comment: @JeffBowman The question's title says "Mockito/JMockit" (and it now has the "jmockit" tag). Now, of course using argument capture does not allow the test to restrict which calls it will match, but that "limitation" is the same with both Mockito and JMockit. So, there is no difference between "my captor" and the one a Mockito test would have; that's all I was saying.